# dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 problem

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 15.04, windows-10

I have a problem with the dual booting. When i start my pc, the screen where i can chose which system to boot comes up. It says ubuntu and a couple of others and then windows 8 even though i have windows 10, and when i try to start it that way, it says insert disk. to get to windows i have to access the bios and change by boot priority, so both ubuntu and windows still work fine, its only the dual boot menu which is weird. 
Edit:
right now i'm trying to update to ubuntu version 15.04 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think updating to 15.04 is a good idea, i was having tons of problems with ubuntu 14.10, but when I upgraded to 15.04 they went away. It's known for being a more stable OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your bootloadeder's config by command `update-grub`. But first make sure you have fully updated system.